# how to utilise diff_drive_controller package in my robot?

Tags: ros, kinematics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I need your help to fill some gaps in my head :)
So I have built a moving robot based on differential driving.
Since it is the most popular drive (because of its simplicity) I searched for available packages and I found **diff_drive_controller**.

As it is stated in the Overview section,
"Control is in the form of a velocity command, that is split then sent on the two wheels of a differential drive wheel base."

So I expect that this controller is subscribed in topic that accepts *cmd_vel* messages as commands, which is true.

But then what about encoders?
I was expecting to provide two topics such as *lwheel* and *rwheel* to get encoders' pulses output but it is not documented.
Similarly, I was expecting to publish in 2 topics the velocities for the wheels (joints).

Yes, I have found the **differential_drive** package (which was discontinued since groovy) but I though to try  **diff_drive_controller** first.

Regards,
Angelos

I'm sure that I miss something and I ask kindly your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266162/how-to-utilise-diff_drive_controller-package-in-my-robot?/) by [angelos.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/22933/angelos.p/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2017-07-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to be able to use the `diff_drive_controller` from `ros_control`, you'll have to write a `hardware_interface` that allows `diff_drive_controller` to communicate with your sensors and actuators. A `hardware_interface` is basically a C++ class that has `read()` and `write()` methods and is a specialisation of a generic `hardware_interface` and knows how to read sensors and write to actuators (or their intermediate registers / whatever) *for your specific hardware platform*.

It's an abstraction that allows the generic `diff_drive_controller` to use your specific hardware, without knowing anything about your hardware.

For a mobile base using a differential drive, the sensors would be the encoders and the actuators would (most likely) be velocity controlled motors.

There are generally two 'types' of `hardware_interface` implementations:

1. those that use ROS msgs to communicate with nodes that implement the actual interface to the hardware
2. those that do not use ROS msgs, but some other means (direct register access, a UDP/TCP connection, etc)

Personally I prefer type 2, but if you already have nodes that expose topics which carry and accept the data you need (such as your `lwheel` and `rwheel` and "2 topics the velocities for the wheels") then a type 1 is obviously a possibility.

See #q263501 for a recent related question.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-12**:
Note that I completely made the *type 1* and *type 2* distinction up, that is not official terminology at all.

It does however reflect the types of implementations I've come across - and written myself.

**Comment by [angelos.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/22933/angelos.p/) on 2017-07-12**:
Thanks gvdhoorn, so I see that I need to research on the implementation of this hardware interface. Yes, I feel that I'm closer to implementation 2 as I have already developed a communication that exchanges data with my controller board (arduino M0) which is not in ROS. Thanks!